# CryptoJS AES encrypt equivalent in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, encryption, cryptojs

I am using 'crypto-js' package in front-end to encrypt values like this:

```
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
var value_to_encrypt = '1-2345-689'
var encrypted_value = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(value_to_encrypt, 'my_secret_key').toString()

==> 'U2FsdGVkX1/JWm47UWAgxMKyf2qC6EukAtk0pZbW3pk='
```

For backend that i am using Rails OpenSSL like this:

```
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new('aes-128-cbc')    
cipher.encrypt    
cipher.key = 'my_secret_key'    
text = cipher.update("1-2345-689") + cipher.final    
encrypted_value = Base64.strict_encode64(text)

==> 'pBTaRw/fZTRkrw4THDCGLQ=='
```

I found few solutions but they all suggested to use 128bit key and iv for encryption in the front-end which is not possible at this stage because i already have a lot of records saved using the same encryption method.

Can anyone please suggest what would be rails equivalent to that method?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to encrypt using key & iv and decrypt it without using them (and vice versa). I had to decrypt the old encrypted data and encrypt that again using iv and key.

In Front-end (reactJs):

```
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(INITIALIZATION_VECTOR)
const key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(ENCRYPTION_KEY)

encrypted_value = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(input,  key,  {mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,  iv : iv}).toString()

decrypted_value = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(input,  key,  {mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,  iv : iv}).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)
```

In Back-end (Ruby on Rails):

```
iv = Base64.decode64(INITIALIZATION_VECTOR)
key = [ENCRYPTION_KEY].pack("H*")
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new('aes-128-cbc')
cipher.encrypt
cipher.key = key
cipher.iv = iv
text = cipher.update(plain_text) + cipher.final
encrypted_text = Base64.strict_encode64(text)
```